# How do I integrate this

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I perform this integration?

$$\int_{0}^b x\frac{2b(b^2-x^2)}{(b^2+x^2)^2} dx = \ ?$$

I tried using integration by parts and arrived at an expression
$$\int_{0}^{b} \frac {6b^3x^3 - 2bx^5}{(b^2+x^2)^3} dx $$

which is worse than the original integral.

Anyway, WolframAlpha says the solution is $b - b\ log(2)$ but refuses to reveal the steps to non-pro users. Damn WolframAlpha.

Comment: Hints: 1. Get rid of $b$ by homogeneity. 2. Use the decomposition $$\frac{2x(1-x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{4x}{(1+x^2)^2}-\frac{2x}{1+x^2}=\left(\frac{-2}{1+x^2}\right)'-(\log(1+x^2))'.$$

Comment: Stephen Wolfram is the one who should be damned, not Wolfram|Alpha, something his little serfs put together that is actually quite handy. He's the one responsible for being a douche.

Comment: @Did What do you mean by "get rid of $b$ by homogeneity"?

Comment: Use the change of variable $x=bt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$2bx\frac {2b^2-b^2-x^2}{(b^2+x^2)^2}=2bx\frac {2b^2}{(b^2+x^2)^2}-2bx\frac 1{b^2+x^2}$$

Now note that you have scalar multiples of $$\left((b^2+x^2)^{-1}\right)'=-2x(b^2+x^2)^{-2}$$ and $$\left(\ln (b^2+x^2)\right)'=2x(b^2+x^2)^{-1}$$ So you can integrate directly.

Using the substitution suggested in the comments tidies things up a bit, but adds another step.